# Creating a Facebook Open Graph object using Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift, facebook-opengraph

I'm creating a Custom Story using Facebook iOS SDK, the app is written in Swift. I've based my code around their documentation example https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/open-graph#createobject.

Everything runs smoothly until I have to create the FBGraphObject

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];
```

in Swift I've rewritten this chunk as:

```
var object = FBGraphObject.openGraphActionForPost()

// specify that this Open Graph object will be posted to Facebook
object.setObject(true, forKey: "provisionedForPost")

// for og:title
object.setObject(description["title"]!, forKey: "title")

// for og:type, this corresponds to the Namespace you've set for your app and the object type name
object.setObject("bppridereport:ride", forKey: "type")

// for og:description
object.setObject(description["description"]!, forKey: "description")

FBRequestConnection.startForPostOpenGraphObject(object, completionHandler: { (connection:FBRequestConnection!, result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in

    if error == nil {
        let objectId = result["id"]

      } else {
          NSLog("Error posting the Open Graph object to the Object API:", error);
      }

  })
```

This gives me an error of: **NSMutableDictionary is not identical to FBOpenGraphObject**, what kinda makes sense, reading the docs a FBOpenGraphObject is just a dressed up NSMutableDictionary so I cast the object as FBOpenGraphObject solving the error

```
var object = FBGraphObject.openGraphActionForPost() as FBOpenGraphObject
```

Problem is, when I now compile this and run the app it crashes on this line... I'm baffled. There's very little out there covering Swift implementation of the Facebook SDK. Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: What is the error message when it crashes?

Comment: @Mike Taverne It looks like this ->

**Thread 1: Signal SIGABRT** on var object = FBGraphObject.openGraphActionForPost() as FBOpenGraphObject

[error screengrab](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2325675/stackoverflow/Social_swift%20error.png)

**swift_dynamicCastObjCProtocolUnconditional**

[error screengrab](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2325675/stackoverflow/Social_swift.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cast the type to FBGraphObject within the call to Facebook.

I use different calls to the one in your example, as I have set up html pages with the metadata , but a refactor of your example would be as follows:

```
var object = FBGraphObject.openGraphActionForPost()

// Code to create object metadata omitted //

FBRequestConnection.startForPostOpenGraphObject(object as FBGraphObject, completionHandler: {
(connection:FBRequestConnection!, result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) in
    if error == nil {
        let objectId = result["id"]
    } else {
       NSLog("Error posting the Open Graph object to the Object API:", error)
   }
})
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the Facebook API so this is at best an educated guess:

```
 var object = FBGraphObject.openGraphActionForPost() as NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject>
```

Comment: Really appreciate the response @Mike. I can see how that would make sense, however, I get a "Cannot specialize non-generic type 'NSMutable Dictionary'" error [error screengrab](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2325675/stackoverflow/Social_swift_generics.png)

Comment: Sorry, Dan, that's what I get for guessing. I looked at this some more today but I don't see a way in Swift to do the equivalent of what they want you to do in ObjC.

Comment: You cannot do that, because the <> mean a completely different thing in Swift. In Objective C: `NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject>` would conform the dictionary to the FBOpenGraphObject protocol.
In Swift, it means to create an NSMutableDictionary which contains a set of FBOpenGraphObjects.

Comment: @ChrisHarrison Thanks for the clarification. I didn't realize the difference in meaning of < >.